Can you explain the conversion of -1234 to int16_t type
Can you explain (from scratch,in plain English) the conversion of the negative integer -1234 to int16_t type?
I have gone through many materials in the internet and got confused.
What would be the binary representation of -1234 in int16_t type?
The code I have tried was:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(void) {
    int16_t a = -1234;
    printf("%x",a);
    return 0;
}

out : fffffb2e

If you printf("%hx",a); you'll get fb2e which is easily converted to 16-bit binary.

@WeatherVane It would be nice if there was a way to get length modifiers such as h from macros in <inttypes.h>.

@IanAbbot such as printf("%" PRIx16, a); ?

@WeatherVane PRIx16 typically expands to "x".

@IanAbbot but printf("%" PRIx16, a); outputs fb2e and not fffffb2e. It expands to "hx".

@WeatherVane printf("%" PRIx16, a); outputs fffffb2e on my system (Linux, GNU libc). Perhaps SCNx16 could be used, but that seems like cheating!

@IanAbbot I don't get it. When int is 32-bit a 16-bit value is promoted to 32 bits anyway. Is the implementation defective, in not understanding the 16 in "PRIx16"?

@WeatherVane In the GNU glibc implementation of the PRI macros, the length modifier is only set for types wider than int. The Microsoft versions also set the length modifier for types narrower than int.

@WeatherVane I think both the glibc and Microsoft versions are standard compliant. The difference in output is due to abusing the x specifier with a signed integer argument.

@Weather Vane, The behaviour of x is only defined for an unsigned int. ("o,u,x,X The unsigned int argument is converted to ...".  "unsigned int" is in bold in original.) In your test, I presume the int16_t was promoted to a larger signed int instead. Undefined behaviour. printf("%" PRIx16, (uint16_t)a); is a valid invocation, though it might not be the one you want.

This doesn't have anything to do with C as such. All numbers in computers are simply stored in binary form. Decimal, hex, strings etc are just convenient forms for humans to display that raw binary data. Including the number format inside source code, which is just there for the benefit of the programmer. If you had been forced to type out some 1111101100101110 each time you need a number in the source code, then any form of programming would have been really painful.

@IanAbbott You can always cheat https://godbolt.org/z/nK934PrzP  :)

@Ian Abbott, Needs to be? Well, it isn't from what I can see. It's only defined for unsigned int. I guess you should technically use (unsigned)u for smaller types, like (void*)p for pointers. That said, signed int and unsigned int always have the same representation for positive numbers.

@ikegami After further consideration, I agree with you and deleted my comment before you posted your comment. printf("%x", (uint16_t)a); is UB (meaning it might work OK), but printf("%" PRIx16, (uint16_t)a); is not UB. By extension, printf("%x", (unsigned char)a); is UB and should be changed to printf("%hhx", (unsigned char)a);.

yeah, %hhx does say it expects a signed char or unsigned char that's been promoted. ("Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing); or [...]". Types names are bold in original.)

Oh, and I should have mentioned that printf("%x", (uint16_t)a); is only UB if INT_MAX is greater than or equal to UINT16_MAX.

That was understood :)

I think C must guarantee that INT_MAX is greater than or equal to CHAR_MAX (but does not guarantee than INT_MAX is greater than or equal to UCHAR_MAX), otherwise printf("%c", "a"[0]); would result in UB. (If INT_MAX were less than CHAR_MAX, the value "a"[0] would be promoted from char to unsigned int and would not match the %c specifier that expects an int, resulting in UB.) This guarantees that printf("%d", "a"[0]); is not UB.

But printf("%hhd", "a"[0]); is UB because %hhd only applies to a signed char, not a char, even if char is signed.

@IanAbbott "printf("%x", (uint16_t)a); is only UB if INT_MAX is greater than or equal to UINT16_MAX" --> Hmm, what UB do you see here? (uint16_t)a well converts to a uint16_t. uint16_t (INT_MAX is greater than or equal to UINT16_MAX) converts to an int (as part of a ... arg) and an int in unsigned range is fine for "%x".

@chux-ReinstateMonica «an int in unsigned range is fine for "%x"» — > I don't know how you justify that. The standard says, "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." And the correct type for "%x" is unsigned int.
